# How do I find the owner of a Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My App Engine is run by a service account. It writes files to a bucket. How can I see the service account as owner of the file objects?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [gsutil ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls) command with the `-L` option:

```
gsutil ls -L gs://your-bucket/your-object
```

This will print the entities which have permissions on the object. One of them will be the service account which created the object:

> {
>
> "email": "your-service-account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
>
> "entity": "user-your-service-account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
>
> "role": "OWNER"
> }

Also from the console in the bucket's page if you click on the 3 dots at the right side of the object and "edit permissions" you will see the same entitites.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not indicate ownership of the object. I have added another service account as role:OWNER to the object with the gsutil acl get/set. It seems to work. Maybe there is no definitive ownership?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by definitive ownership?

Comment: looks like it changed to gsutil ls -L -b gs://your_bucket bla bla bla

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "new" [gcloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) command which [supersedes gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-cli-for-your-data-transfers)  while implementing all of the gsuil features.

```
gcloud storage ls -L gs://your-bucket/your-object
```